# oauth/initiate says page not found

Tags: magento

I am not able to get a request token from the oauth/initiate page because it says page not found. What could be the problem?

I have created an oAuth customer, given the appropriate REST roles and attributes. Also, appended the consumer key, secret, nonce etc. in the authorization for the oAuth request.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Oauth will give you page not found if the request params are incorrect. It's likely your client isn't sending the parameters correctly, or your signature doesn't match the one Magento is calculating.

I added some temporary logging to the OAuth server to try and track down the issue.

Add this to file `app/code/core/Mage/Oauth/Model/Server.php` after `line 594`, it will help you see what specific oauth error is being raised

```
Mage::log($response, Zend_Log::DEBUG, 'oauth.log');
```

Try your initiate request again, and then check var/log/oauth.log to see what the error is.

**Don't even think about doing this on a production system, and ensure you roll back your changes afterwards. You should never modify core files other than for temporary debugging.**

Comment: And this question is almost a year old, well hopefully it'll be helpful to somebody some day.